# How to download more than 10000 data from sumologic

Tags: api, download, sumologic

I am new to sumologic. I am trying to use API to download more than 10000 data.

I already generate access id and keys like this:

[image]

But when I try to open the url: https://api.au.sumologic.com/api/v1/search/jobs, I have the following erro info:

[image]

I am following the introduction from https://help.sumologic.com/APIs/Search-Job-API/About-the-Search-Job-API.  I do now know where I did something wrong. Maybe because I am in the company and there is a firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That url https://api.au.sumologic.com/api.v1/search/jobs should be sent a query via a post as directed in the documentation you included.  This should return an ID via a json response which if you append it to the end of that url should contain the response for the query for 5 minutes...this can be extended for up to 8 hours by continued polling per the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some sort of script to call the API (which is the URL you're trying to get to) via [REST](https://restful.io/an-introduction-to-api-s-cee90581ca1b) calls. It isn't something you'll be able to pull up in a browser. I recommend using the Python SDK for Sumo Logic: https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumologic-python-sdk.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But could you please give me more details about how to use it? Maybe this is too basic for you. But I am still confused because this is the first time that I use API or SDK.